# The CXX compiler identification is unknown - CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:101

Tags: macos, cmake

I have problems to install a particular module.

Link to instructions if you want: [Here](https://github.com/dbbs-lab/cereb-nest).

Now: I follow exactly the steps.

The lasts command lines are:

```
mkdir $HOME/cereb-nest-build
cd $HOME/cereb-nest-build
```

And you can see that the folder path is correct.

This is the print on terminal:

```
(base) myusername@MBP-di-Simone cereb-nest-build % cmake -Dwith:nest=$HOME/opt/anaconda3/envs/nest218/bin/nest-config $HOME/cereb-nest
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:101 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    /usr/local/miniconda/conda-bld/nest-simulator_1580129234212/_build_env/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/myusername/cereb-nest-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/myusername/cereb-nest-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And it generate two files:

- CMakeCache.txt
- CMakeFiles Folder (with others files)

I see every step and every folders that was create but I have this error always.
I check an update of CMake, I see that this script was tested with CMake 3.2.2 but I can't see new version from 3.19 but can't understand the problem.

Thank you everyone for answers.

Comment: Have you checked, if the location in the output is the actual location of the compiler? Also the colon in `-Dwith:nest=...` seems weird. In `-D` command line parameters of cmake the name of the cache variable type follows after the colon; `nest` is not a variable type though.

Comment: I did seam steps with linux and works perfectly. I can't understand. I use Mac and ok there are any problems sometimes but this is so strange.